# Return true doesn't work for javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Javascript code that returns true if a certain checkbox is checked.

```
document.getElementById("accept").addEventListener("click", function(event){
if(document.getElementById('hck').checked == false){
  event.preventDefault();
}
else
{
 return true;
}   

});
```

This is the Javascript code

```
<input class="btn btn-success btn-lg mx-auto btnac" type="submit" id="accept" name="accept" value="Accept">
```

This is the button and it's inside a form.

I had put in two print statements earlier to see if it enters the clauses, and it does, but it doesn't go to the Django function and return the appropriate page on return true.

Comment: Instead of Javascript, you could've also added a `required` attribute to the checkbox with the id `hck`.

Comment: That is true. I didn't think of that. I'ts so funny cause I've used that before. I'll use 'required'. that's much easier.  But why isn't it still working though?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you better use the `required` attribute for the case

Answer (score 1):

You can use the required attribute as suggested by others already but to also resolve your original attempt here's a working example of what you tried to achieve.

The form submits when checkbox is checked otherwise it doesn't.

```js
document.getElementById("accept").addEventListener("click",  function(event){
 if(document.getElementById('hck').checked) {
  console.log('checkbox is checked');
  return true;
 }
 console.log('checkbox is not checked');
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div>
 <form action="#something" method="get">  
  <input type="checkbox" id="hck" name="hck" value="Test Box">
  <br/>
   <input class="btn" type="submit" id="accept" name="accept" value="Accept">
 </form>
</div>
```